# Recursion array adding positive numbers

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have an array that takes numbers. One of my methods is to count the number of positive numbers in the array. So if they enter 2 3 4 5 6 and a 0 to terminate the program. It should input print out Postive numbers: 5 but instead it prints out Positive Numbers : 4. Its misses the last number. However, if i do 2 3 4 5 -1 4 0 {0 terminates} it prints out the correct numbers of positive numbers in this case 5. I've done some debugging but cant seem to figure it out. Any help?

```
public static int countPositive(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{   
    if (startIndex == endIndex) 
    {   
        if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
        {   
            return 1;
        }   
        else
            return 0;      
    }   
    else
    {       
        if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
        {       
            return 1 + countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex); 
        }
        else        
            return countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Your indentation is all over the place, you should correct that so that your code is easier to read. Eclipse can do that for you.

Comment: It works fine for me. If I use `countPositive(new int[] { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0, 4)` result is `5`.

Comment: What are the index start and end you're using?

Comment: He probably is using indexStart as 1 where it should be 0

Comment: No I am starting it at 0

Comment: Perhaps you're passing in an `endIndex` that is one too low, e.g. `3` for an array of length 5?

Comment: What happened to your code?

Comment: @AnnL. The code was removed in an edit;  I've rolled back, because it really is important for the question.

Comment: I copied and pasted your method and it worked fine for both cases. I think the problem is in the way you assign numbers to array or scanning user input. Perhaps you should check your loop condition because I guess you are using a method that scans user input inside of that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Goin to paste all the code, so first the whole code:

```
public class JavaApplication5 {

    public static int countPositive(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{   
    if (startIndex == endIndex) 
    {   
        if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
        {   
            return 1;
        }   
        else
            return 0;      
    }   
    else
    {       
        if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
        {       
            return 1 + countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex); 
        }
        else        
            return countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex);     
    }
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i=countPositive(new int[] { -3, 30, 40, 55, 62}, 0, 4);
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

This code returned me 4 4 positive numbers:30,40,55,62.
You can play with array and strt and end index.

```
int i=countPositive(new int[] { -3, 30, 40, 55, 62,-3, 43}, 0, 6);
```

The code above returned me 5-the number of positive numbers.

```
int i=countPositive(new int[] { -3, 30, 40, 55, 62,-3, 43}, 3, 6);
```

Returned me 3 positive numbers: from 55,62,-3 and 43 they are 55,62 and 43.
Try yourself once more.

Answer (score 0):

It is terrible, that the code has the same logic in 2 different else branches. Better:

```
if (startIndex > endIndex) return 0;
else 
    return
       (numbers[startIndex] > 0 ? 1 : 0) 
       + countPositives(numbers, startIndex+1, endIndex);
```

Also, to count the whole array do:

```
countPositives(numbers, 0, length.numbers-1);
```