# Array Postive Numbers not added properly

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

I have an array that takes numbers. One of my methods is to count the number of positive numbers in the array. So if they enter 2 3 4 5 6 and a 0 to terminate the program, it should print out Positive numbers: 5, but instead it prints out Positive Numbers : 4. It misses the last number. However, if I do 2 3 4 5 -1 4 0 {0 terminates} it prints out the correct number of positive numbers, in this case 5. I've done some debugging but can't seem to figure it out. Any help?

```
    public static void main (String args[]) throws IOException
    {
    int i = 0;
    int [] nums;
    nums = new int [100];

    InputStreamReader inRead = new InputStreamReader(System.in);   // 
    BufferedReader buffRead = new BufferedReader(inRead);
    String line = buffRead.readLine();



        while (line.equals("0") == false && i<100)      
        {       
            i++;        
            line = buffRead.readLine();     
            nums[i]=(int) Double.parseDouble(line);     

        }




    System.out.print ("The minimum number is " + findMin (nums, 0, nums.length - 1) + ('\n'));
    System.out.println("Sum of the numbers at odd indices: " + computeSumAtOdd(nums, 0 , nums.length -1 ) + ('\n') );
    System.out.println("The total count of positive numbers is  " + countPositive(nums,0,nums.length -1));
}

 public static int countPositive(int[] numbers, int startIndex, int endIndex)
 {   
     if (startIndex == endIndex) 
     {   
         if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
         {   
              return 1;
         }   
         else
              return 0;      
     } else
     {       
       if (numbers[startIndex] > 0)        
       {       
        return 1 + countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex); 
       }
       else        
        return countPositive(numbers, startIndex +1, endIndex);     
    }
 }
```

Comment: This code looks OK.  Are you sure the code inputting into the array is correct?  Also mixing if else with and without braces like that is a pretty terrible coding practice, do one or the other not both.

Comment: I have a feeling your endIndex is not calculated correctly. See what the call is for it.

Comment: System.out.println("The total count of positive numbers is  " + countPositive(nums,0,nums.length -1));

Comment: As I told you [before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19868543/recursion-array-adding-positive-numbers#comment29553508_19868543) this code seems to be working fine. Your problem is probably somewhere else. Could you show us how are you reading and storing data from user and using this method?

Comment: what are the values coming into the function for the first time?

Comment: I've added the begginning of my code. Keep in mind that I have other methods in the program that work well and did not include

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code

```
String line = buffRead.readLine();

while (line.equals("0") == false && i < 100) {
    i++;
    line = buffRead.readLine();
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
}
```

you are ignoring first number that user gave. In case it is not `0` you should put it in array but instead you are reading next value. Try maybe this way

```
String line = buffRead.readLine();

while (line.equals("0") == false && i < 100) {
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
    i++;
    line = buffRead.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code you're showing us here is valid and works.

Try outputting the values in the array before you call this to see what they are.

For example, if your input is an array called numbers, put earlier in your code:

```
for ( int i=0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(numbers[i]);
}
```

and try and get a good look at what is going on in your array.

Also, be sure when you call countPositive, that you input:

```
countPositive(numbers, 0, numbers.length - 1)
```

and be sure that you're not cutting anything off with the wrong inputs.

Answer (score 0):

The first number entered will not be included in the array (see my embedded comment)

```
String line = buffRead.readLine(); //<--read a line...

while (line.equals("0") == false && i < 100) {
    i++;
    line = buffRead.readLine(); <-- read another line, what happened to the last line?
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(line);
}
System.out.println("The total count of positive numbers is  " + countPositive(nums, 0, nums.length - 1));
```